# Which values to use for scaling out-of-sample PCA data?

Tags: pca

I have centered and scaled inputs via `prcomp ()`:

```
prOut<-prcomp(trainSet[,2:4],scale = TRUE,scores=TRUE)
```

I now want to use my completed model on new (future) data.
I assume the correct approach is to use the training data `prOut$scale` and `prOut$center` values and apply them to prior to calculating the principal component scores for my new data?

It doesn't seem right to scale the new data using the scale and center values for the new data set.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should use the center and scaling from the `prcomp` object.

An easy way to realize that center and variance of the new data set is not suitable is:
assume the new data set consists of one row only. Its center would be the case itself and a scaling cannot be calculated.